# LaTeX Error: Command \etalchar already defined

Tags: macros, errors, packages

Has anyone ever come across the following error, and how would I solve it? Quick googling did not seem to help, and I guess that the issue may not be with \etalchar (I don't define it ever), but some conflicting packages.

```
LaTeX Error: Command \etalchar already defined.
               Or name \end... illegal, see p.192 of the manual.

See the LaTeX manual or LaTeX Companion for explanation.
Type  H <return>  for immediate help.
 ...                                              

l.1 \newcommand{\etalchar}[1]{$^{#1}$}

?
```

Comment: A search of this cite https://tex.stackexchange.com/search?q=%5Cetalchar+ reveals that the command exists already for use in bibliography applications.  It is defined, for example, in the `alphadin.bst` file (https://github.com/youkan/abschlussarbeit-latex/blob/master/alphadin.bst)

Comment: Thanks, helped. I happened to call for bibliography twice. Deleting the second help removed this error. Feel free to post an answer, I'll accept.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A search of this site, http://tex.stackexchange.com/search?q=%5Cetalchar+ reveals that the command `\etalchar` exists already for use in bibliography applications. It is defined, for example, in the `alphadin.bst` file (https://github.com/youkan/abschlussarbeit-latex/blob/master/alphadin.bst)

If the OP was not himself defining the command explicitly, it could mean that there is a package conflict, in which two separate packages are both trying to define the macro `\etalchar`.

However, based on the comment from the OP, it appears that a redundant call was accidentally made to the bibliography, which had the effect of trying to execute the same set of code twice, containing the `\etalchar` definition.  Thus, an error was thrown, as a result of the redundancy.

Relevant part of `alphadin.bst` code:

```
FUNCTION {begin.bib}
{ et.al.char.used
    { "\newcommand{\etalchar}[1]{$^{#1}$}" write$ newline$ }
    'skip$
  if$
  preamble$ empty$
    'skip$
    { preamble$ write$ newline$ }
  if$
  "\begin{thebibliography}{"  longest.label  * "}" * write$ newline$
  newline$
  "% this bibliography is generated by alphadin.bst [8.2] from 2005-12-21"
  write$ newline$
  newline$
  "\providecommand{\url}[1]{\texttt{#1}}"
  write$ newline$
  "\expandafter\ifx\csname urlstyle\endcsname\relax"
  write$ newline$
  "  \providecommand{\doi}[1]{doi: #1}\else"
  write$ newline$
  "  \providecommand{\doi}{doi: \begingroup \urlstyle{rm}\Url}\fi"
  write$ newline$
}
```

Answer (score 0):

As suggested [here](https://www.fogman.de/?p=165), changing `\newcommand` to `\providecommand` in your desired `.bst`-file worked for me:

1. Locate the `.bst`-file for the `\bibliographystyle` you want to use, e.g., `/usr/share/texlive/texmf-dist/bibtex/bst/bibtex/alpha.bst` on Linux or `C:\MiKTeX 2.9\bibtex\bst\bibtex\alpha.bst` on Windows
2. Edit the file and navigate to the `FUNCTION {begin.bib}` section
3. Change `\newcommand{\etalchar}[1]{$^{#1}$}` to `\providecommand{\etalchar}[1]{$^{#1}$}`
4. Run (`sudo`) `texhash`
5. Clean auxilary files in your LaTeX project (e.g., using Tools - Clean Auxillary Files) in TeXstudio
6. Recompile your document